# Using texture in GL shader in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to use GLKTextureLoader to load a texture into a custom shader written in GLSL. It loads all the vertex and fragment shader bits just fine, but when I try to load a texture it quits.

This is how I'm trying to accomplish it:

```
do { 
    guard let CGImage =  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image01").cgImage else { print("no CGImage"); return nil}
    let texture = try GLKTextureLoader.texture(with: CGImage, options: nil)
} catch {
    print("Texture not loaded", (error))
}
```

it seems to get the CGImage, but fails on the `GLKTextureLoader.texture` bit.
Here is the error:

```
Error Domain=GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain Code=17 "(null)" UserInfo={GLKTextureLoaderErrorKey=Invalid EAGL context}
```

I've tried logging the GL errors with  `NSLog("GL Error = %u", glGetError());` but that just gives me `GL Error = 0`

This is the first real project I'm trying with swift, is there something obvious I'm missing? Or is mixing ARKit with GLSL shaders just impossible?

Comment: What renderer are you using your custom shader with? If you're using `ARSCNView` you don't get GL shaders because that renderer always uses Metal. (SceneKit automatically translates [`shaderModifiers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable/1523348-shadermodifiers) written in GLSL to Metal shaders, but those won't reference GL textures.)

Comment: I am using ARSCNView. Thanks so much for commenting by the way. How would I put a vertex and fragment shader in the shaderModifiers? Theres a custom shader i need to implement that makes a model appear with a fancy effect. How can I add the textures without the textureloader?